# Add object and child in NSTreeviewController

Tags: macos, treeview, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have struggle upto 2 days in NSTreeviewController class. Here is my code

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"isGroup",
                            @"Desktop",@"name",
                            [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Science", @"name",nil],
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Art", @"name", nil],
                             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"History", @"name", nil],nil], @"children", nil];

[treecontroller addObject:dic];
```

I have added TreeController Keypaths as 'children'.

Actually my application scope is want to show the file directories. like as follows

I have attached the image [image: NSTreeview]

that is i want shows the finder here.

how can i add to here. pls help. i'm waiting. thanks in advance. sorry for my mistaken english

Comment: Now that we know what you wanted: What does actually happen? Do you get anything at all? Also, does your dictionary model work if you replace instead of add objects using `setContent:`? (Good test to see if you set up the model object right in the first place)

Comment: @ctietze i have completed what i expected. except change color to nstextfieldcell text. that only i need. could u help to how to set color programmatically to specific textcell in nstreecontroller

Comment: @ctietze And its not showing chinese character and tamil character. that the problem still facing

Comment: Please share your solution below for reference. Also, I'd recommend opening a new question for the color thing and provide more detail. (OR rephrase this one)